# Is this a true hadith about wilayat of Ali R.A

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, shia-sunni, shia-imam

Ibn Abbas: Ali gave someone his ring in alms while he was in the state of rukūʿ in prayer. The Prophet (S) asked the beggar, "Who gave you this ring?" He replied, "That man during rukūʿ." Then Allah sent down the verse, "Your Waliyy is only Allah, His Messenger, and those who believe, those who establish ṣalāt and pay zakāt while they are bowing." (Kanz al-Ummal, by sunni author Ali ibn Abd-al-Malik al-Hindi)

Can someone send me a link of Kanz ul Ummal online either an Internet Archive copy or any other copy and tell me the pg number of this.

Btw some ppl say this is fabrictaed. Is this true?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/112081/